# The Walking Dead - can I improve my course of the game?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

Does backing up to a certain stage in the past games keep even earlier actions, and can I improve those that have already been made​​?

For example: I did A and after it I did B. When I come back to the point with situation B will it keep A and allow me to make a different choice for B? (For example: giving someone a different answer) Or is it nothing that can be corrected during the game?

Comment: Your question is kinda confusing. Make it clearer and I should be able to answer.

Answer (score 2):

It keeps all decisions BEFORE the rewind point, but eliminates any choices after.  For example. Let's call these rewind points "Checkpoints". When you rewind you can go back and choose which "Checkpoint" to rewind to. SO let's assume you have proceeded through a total of 5 checkpoints. And then let's say a decision you made on checkpoint 4 is bothering you a lot, so you decide to rewind back to 3, or the beginning of 4.  When you rewind you will keep all data from BEFORE where you are checkpointing, but lose all data after. So if you rewind to the beginning of checkpoint 4, you keep all decisions on checkpoints 1 through 4, but the progress after the checkpoint is like it never happened.

Very good for refining and perfecting your decisions while playing the game, or trying different choices to see which one you prefer.